# Display success message in Django after S3 download

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to trigger a download of an AWS S3 object using Django 3.

**views.py**

```
def pagelanding(request):
    if some_condition:
        URL='URL_to_s3_file'
        return redirect(URL)
    return render(request,'page.html')
```

So far everything works fine, when I trigger the condition in my template, the download is triggered. The problem is that I would like to display a success message. Since the `redirect` is occupied by the download directive, I can't for example use the [Django messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/) on the template.

Is there any way to trigger the download and display the message at the same time?

Comment: Is Authentication  required?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanFareed no

Comment: File downloaded into separate tab or the current tab? What kind of information you will displaying on redirect URL template? Is redirect URL is Django URL?

Comment: so when I call `redirect(URL)` with the URL being an S3 object, a download will be triggered when `some_condition` is fulfilled. When this is done, I would like to display a Django message saying `file downloaded`.

Comment: You can add tag into your template with success message. 2nd approach is calling ajax request when response is positive then display success message with using Jquery or other.

Comment: Hi @MuhammadFaizanFareed, I can add a tag in my template with the success messages, but it will only display when I redirect to my template. The problem is already use redirect to download the file. Do you see where my problem is? I can't use redirect twice. Also I am not knowledgeable about jquery/ajax etc..